# Organization External Error ORA-29913 ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating external table in Oracle as follows:

```
create or REPLACE directory PATH_ENTITY as 'C:\001Billing\loadFiles';
```

```
create table DWH_TABLE (
    SECUENCIA VARCHAR2(150),
    CAMPO2 VARCHAR2(150)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( type oracle_loader 
  default directory PATH_ENTITY 
  access parameters 
  ( fields terminated by ''|''
    missing field values are null
  ) 
  location ('textfile.txt') 
);
```

Text file content

```
20200820090816024009|20200820090816023905
```

when I read the table I get the following error

```
select * from DWH_TABLE;
```

[Error ORA-29913 ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0V5f.png)

Oracle Version

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error mesasge said - there is a problem with single quoted string

replace the invalid quoted string

```
 fields terminated by ''|''
```

with

```
 fields terminated by '|'
```

Comment: You could be right, but the error message doesn't say in particular about what you have mentioned and the reason could be multiple. e.g. `file doesn't exist` , `file is corrupted`, `grants are missing` ...

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 please read the fourth line of the exception: `KUP-01005  syntax error: found "single-quoted-string" expecting ...`

Comment: As i said in this case you are right in this case but what I intend is, you have to a clear about the answer because the error ORA-29913 and KUP-01005 are not same until some one explicitly open the link.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the necessary grants to are missing for the current user on the directory you have created,

Could you give the grants (replace `username` with actual user of yours) for `read` and `write` as required and try then,

```
grant read on directory path_entity to username;
grant write on directory path_entity to username;
```